# Splitting a string using a Regex with or statements

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to split a string using a regex which will ideally split the string on every whitespace character, underscore, and uppercase letter.

Currently what I have is:

`/(\s+|_+|[A-Z]+)/`

But I can only get it to split the string on either one of those conditions and not all. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The current (now revised) regex above will split a string on uppercase, whitespace, and underscores...however it is splitting it like so:

`'hello World Goodbye' = ['hello', 'W', 'orld', 'G', 'oodbye']`

I want to split the string on uppercase letters but not after, like so:

`['hello', 'World', 'Goodbye']`

Comment: `A-Z+` looks wrong, shouldn't this be `[A-Z]+`

Comment: You're right, that seems to fix part of my problem. I'll update my question.

Comment: show the input string and the expected result

Comment: It seems like you actually don't want to split on uppercase letters.

Comment: I think I'm using the wrong wording here. I want to separate the string when it reaches an uppercase letter, but not after. If that's even possible with a regex.

Comment: "when it reaches an uppercase letter, but not after." - according to this condition what should be the final expected result for all that?

Comment: Does charcase really matter here? How is `"hello world goodbye"` supposed to be splitted? If it should be `"hello"`, `"world"` and `"goodbye"` then just remove the `[A-Z]+` at all, final regex could be `/[ _]+/`

Comment: Why is the word "hello" split out, it doesn't begin with an uppercase letter? It seems that you just want to split on whitespace, with an additional split at underscores?

Comment: Hey everyone, sorry for the confusion. My intent is to be able to parse any string with underscores, whitespace, or uppercase letters and place hyphens between those "words". However strings may sometimes come in the form of `helloWorldGoodbye`, which are clumped together in camel case and harder to separate.

Comment: @Jose: please edit the question to include what you just wrote in comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment:

> My intent is to be able to parse any string with underscores, whitespace, or uppercase letters and place hyphens between those "words". However strings may sometimes come in the form of `helloWorldGoodbye`, which are clumped together in camel case and harder to separate.

To split on a space or an underscore, use a character class `[\s_]+`. To additionally split *before* a capital letter, use a look-ahead.

Altogether, that would look like:

### `/[\s_]+|(?=[A-Z])/`

And you can use it like this:

```js
var str = "HelloWorld good_bye";

str = str.split(/[\s_]+|(?=[A-Z])/).join("-");

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE4sU8/2)

```
"hello World Goodbye" -> "hello-World-Goodbye"

"hello_World_Goodbye" -> "hello-World-Goodbye"

"helloWorldGoodbye" -> "hello-World-Goodbye"
```

Comment: There is no provision to split on whitespace in this situation `hello world`

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = "Hello World Good_bye CruelWorld";
var y = x.split(/\s+|_|(?=[A-Z])/);
console.log(y);
// ["Hello", "World", "Good", "bye", "Cruel", "World"]
```

this uses a *positive lookahead assertion*.

But what about "BOB"? Presumably he should not be split, so the capital should be followed by a lowercase character:

```
var x = "Hello World Good_bye CruelWorld BOB";
var y = x.split(/\s+|_|(?=[A-Z][a-z])/);
console.log(y);
// ["Hello", "World", "Good", "bye", "Cruel", "World", "BOB"]
```

This doesn't cover every possible variation but does meet the question as described.

---

A further attempt to cover different eventualities:

```
var x = "Hello World WhatABeautifulDay Good_bye CruelWorld BOB TaDa";
var y = x.split(/\s+|_|(?=[A-Z][a-z])/);
var z = y.map(function (obj) {
    return obj.replace(/([a-z])(?=[A-Z]$)/, '\$1-');
}).join('-');
console.log(z);
// Hello-World-What-A-Beautiful-Day-Good-bye-Cruel-World-BOB-Ta-Da
```

Comment: But then what if the word is one character long? Such as `whatABeautifulDay`?

Comment: I think you could pull it off without a look-behind, but you would have to use something other than `.split()`. I'm really interested in how it could be done. I'll work on it too.

Comment: Okay, I tried. But then it came to my attention that it would only work if BOB was the last thing in the string. Otherwise, there would be no way to detect the following word. I think BOB and camelCase are incompatible.

Comment: @4castle I'm not certain what you mean with BOB being the last thing? I've added my attempt to my answer for reference.

Comment: That's epic! What I meant was that it wouldn't work if BOB was followed directly by another word (no space or underscore after it). That is good enough for me though. Bravo!

Comment: @4castle Thank you :). It does actually work if removing the space, `BOBTaDa` becomes `BOB-Ta-Da`. Ta Da!

Answer (score 1):

Split conditions

Removal: on whitespace, underscore
Keep: upper case ahead

Regex `[\s_]+|(?=[A-Z])`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=[A-Z]+)|[ _]
```

It matches space, underscore, and before uppercase letter.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QHEzScC4uYsLgOUY)